# Combining more then one xml's in one xml for haarCascades object detection

Tags: xml, opencv, object-detection

Can we add more then one xml's in one xml for detecting more then one objects in a frame(Image)?

e.g: I want to detect nose and face at the same time. OpenCV contains face and nose in both files, but I want their combination to detect both at the same time.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just do the detection two times with two separate classifiers, once for faces and once for noses? You can do both separately or try to find nose only on previously detected faces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. New OpenCV sample for [face-detection](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/python2/facedetect.py) comes with this property.Check it out.

See the result below. It has detected face and eyes in the same image.

[image]

Comment: Link is dead. Can you give an abstract of the solution?

Comment: this is the new link : http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/samples/python2/facedetect.py